# postgres software configuration to achieve 15000 statements per sec

Tags: postgresql

I have system of

```
17.9GB 
64-bit 2 cores each 5346 bogomips
```

I have a postgres server 8.4 , my requirement is to run

5000 insert statement

5000 update statement

5000 select statement

I want all this 15000 statements to be run in a second ( may be my expectation is too high )

Please tell me the right postgres configuration for this

Note : IO respond time should not have much deviation time to time ( should be static ).

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Your expectation is too high.

Comment: Should your statements be run in separate transactions? Do you need guaranteed disk write after each?

Comment: normally 50-70 transactions for 1 normal computer. that is maximum

Comment: Use a SSD (or RAID) if this is an option (I know sounds stupid, but this is the easiest way IMO)

Answer (score 2):

Push as many statements in a single transaction as possible. Optimize the [Write Ahead Log](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-wal.html) to write all these statements together to disk.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need an IO subsystem that's quite impressive to keep up.  I've got a machine with 48 Magny Cours cores and 128 Gig RAM and 34 spinning 15k SAS drives that can sustain about 8000 transactions per second, which is right in the range of what you're looking for.

I could likely do that on far fewer cores, but for what these machines do they need all the CPU they can get.

For you the number of cores will likely need to be numbered in the dozen or more, and you'll need something on the order of a dozen or so SSD drives or 30 to 100 spinning SAS drives to do it.

Also, how big will your db be?  You've really only given a tiny bit of the information needed to answer this question.

Comment: we have 20 tables in our schema , my expectation is 5000 update and 500 select statement should run in a second ,insert can take some more secods , I requuest u to tell with the aboive configuration along with a proper postgres configuration how many insert , select , update  is possible !